# Typescript - property scan does not exist on type Subject...?

Tags: typescript, emit, subject, behaviorsubject

I could not compile [this](https://github.com/NiLinli/ng-book2-angular-6-r68-code-samples/blob/master/redux/redux-chat/tutorial/06b-rx-store.ts) code on Visual Studio Code Editor. First, I was getting an error like `has no exported member 'X', X for BehaviorSubject, Subject`.
So, I changed the import statements as follows:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

which made the import error disappear.
But, now I get the following error, while trying to compile it using tsc command:

[image: error: while trying to execute <code>tsc .\06b-rx-store.ts</code> on cmd.]

I changed the emit to next which solved `property 'emit' does no exist` error. But `property 'scan' does not exist` error is still there. Which I believe has to do with the settings in .json file. But I cannot figure out what setting should be changed.

So, what do I miss here? Any help is much appreciated. If you get the code compile, could you describe how you did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emit` is a method that is specific to Angular [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) that *currently* relies on RxJS `Subject`.

Since `EventEmitter` was specifically designed to handle change detection it's not recommended to use as general purpose subject in Angular applications.

`EventEmitter` `emit` is a wrapper over subject `Subject` `next` method, so `emit` should be replaced with `next`.

`scan` operator should be imported with:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/scan';
```

And this is already done in linked code.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I changed emit to next. That part looks ok now. But I can't get it compile because of the scan operator. I think it has to do something with the json files. But I can't solve it at the moment since I just started typing in Angular and TypeScript. Please, could you compile it yourself and see if you get the same error? if you compile successfully, can you then give me the steps you have taken? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The folder you've linked, redux/redux-chat/tutorial file isn't supposed to be compiled. It seems that it's supposed to run with ts-node. It has problems with ts-node version specified in package.json. I have it installed globally (`npm i -g ts-node@3` if you don't have it), `ts-node ./06b-rx-store.ts` results in errors but there are no errors you're referring to.

Comment: It also has packages missing in in `redux/redux-chat` project, try to run `npm i -S rxjs-compat` there. I had to remove first line in redux/redux-chat/tutorial/06b-rx-store.ts, `/// <reference...` and change `noEmitHelpers` option in redux/redux-chat/tutorial/tsconfig.json from `true` to `false`. Then it ran. The whole repo is a mess and it's not workable out of the box. I'd suggest to report this in repo issues.

Comment: Glad it worked. That's a tough experience, considering that these are examples for devs who read the book and aren't supposed to know the whole thing yet. I guess these are the examples from a dev who isn't affiliated with book authors.